# jQuery center a scrolling element on the page

Tags: jquery

I've got a small jQuery script that does the following:
1. Checks the height of the div that will move (.product_page-left)
2. Checks the height of the container for the above element (.product-content-columns)
3. Increases the top-margin of the .product_page-left div equal to the amount of pixels scrolled by the user
4. Stops the scrolling function if the .product_page-left div hits the bottom or top of the containing div.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).scroll(function(){
        var offsetHeight = 200;
        var marginTop = $(window).scrollTop() - offsetHeight;
        var limit = $(".product-content-columns").height() - $(".product_page-left").height();
        if(marginTop < limit & marginTop > 0)
            $(".product_page-left").css("margin-top",marginTop);
        });
    </script>
```

This is all working fine and good, with but one issue. I added the variable "offsetHeight" and gave it a value of 200 in order to keep the moving div from resting on the bottom of the page. However, the 200 pixel offset only centers the moving div for screens with my resolution.

I need to somehow modify the offsetHeight variable to center the moving div for all screen resolutions. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

You can view this live on my site at: 
http://customshop.yandasmusic.com/custom-bass-guitars/build-your-own-music-man-classic-sting-ray-4